# Azure integration account arm template: how to include a liquid template inline

Tags: azure-devops, liquid, azure-logic-apps

Ive created an azure arm template for my integration account, which is to include an inline Liquid template.

If i deploy from visual studio, it works, but deploying from devOps gives the error:

```
##[error]Error: Ensure the Template file ( 'D:\a\r1\a\projName\drop\IntegrationAccName\ARM\IntegrationAcc.template.json' ) is valid. Task failed while parsing with     following error: Unexpected token 
 in JSON at position 1420
```

position 1420 is the exact start of the liquid content. Sample content is shown below.
The escaped doublequotes are necessary in the output of the liquid, to wrap around the values.

Ive tried a few content types, text, json, liquid and all end up with the same error.
Appreciate any expertise on this.

[image]

Note, there is a comma between the content & contentType keys, its just not visible in that screenshot.

Comment: I have no guarantee that it solves your issue, however working with Liquid and Logic Apps I found that better is used single quote in liquid template. Can you check if it solves your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this by binary chopping the problem down to a tiny liquid file.
The parser does not like cr or lf. Minifing the liquid to a single line allowed it to deploy!

Comment: That's great you fixed it! You can accept above answer of yours.